# Calculus inverse function solving for $f^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, inverse

1. Show that the function $f(x) = x^5 -x^3 +2x$ is invertible. Compute the derivative of $f^{-1}$
   at 2.

To find $f^{-1}$ I switched $x$ and $y$ which gave me $x = y^5 - y^3 + 2y$

this is where i got stuck because I am not sure how to solve for y after that step.

Can the $y^5 - y^3$ become $y^2$?

Comment: You will not succeed in finding an explicit formula for $x$ in terms of $y$. Neither would I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function $f:\mathbb R\to\text{range(f)}$ is invertible, if its derivative, which is here $f'(x)=5x^4-3x^2+2$, is positive. The positivity can be easily checked, since $f'(x)$ has no zeros, is continuous and has one positive value. In particular $f(1)=2$, so that $(f^{-1}(2))'=1/f'(1)=1/4$.

Comment: Thank you! Why did you choose to evaluate the function at x=1?

Comment: @user71317: $f$ is either always positive or always negative. $f(1) = 2$ says that it's always positive.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the last question for a start:  No, you certainly can't replace $y^5 - y^3$ by $y^2$.  (Replace $y$ by almost any number you like and you will see this.)

You have probably learnt that a function is invertible if and only if it is a bijection.  It is going to be *much* easier to show that your $f$ is a bijection (i.e. both one-to-one and onto) than to find an explicit inverse function (and note that the question doesn't ask you to find the inverse!).

Answer (score 1):

- $f'(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial in $x^2$: factor it. if this is positive everywhere or negative everywhere, then $f(x)$ is invertible
- plug some simple arguments into $f(x)$ until the expression matches $2$, and you'll find $f^{-1}(2)$

Answer (score 1):

We claim $f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$.

Consider $f'(x)=5x^4-3x^2+2 = 5(x^2-\frac{3}{10})^2+\frac{31}{20}>0$. So $f(x)$ is strictly monotonically increasing, which implies $f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$.

Let $g=f^{-1}$. Then $g(2)=1$ as $f(1)=2$. Hence $g'(2)=\cfrac{1}{f'(g(2))}=\cfrac{1}{f'(1)}=\cfrac{1}{4}$

Comment: This is wrong, $$\frac{df^{-1}}{dy} (2) \neq (\frac{df}{dx}(2))^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have fixed that.

Comment: why did you evaluate f(1)?

Comment: Because we need to find g(2) first if we want to calculate g'(2) using the formula for the derivative of the inverse, which is $$g'(a)=\cfrac{1}{f'(g(a))}$$ You can find details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = x^5 -x^3 +2x$, $f(1)=2.$

$$(f^{-1})'(2)=\frac{1}{f'(1)}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: why did you evaluate f(1)?